# Cant Load Data from JSON in FlotChart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello i have problem to load data in flotchart.js

here's the original code that works

```
var pageviews = [
            [1,2],
            [2, 3]
        ];
        var visitors = [
            [1, 3],
            [2, 2]
        ];
var plot = $.plot($("#site_statistics"), [{
            data: pageviews,
            label: "Unique Visits"
        }, {
            data: visitors,
            label: "Page Views"
        }]);
```

but when i change the data that i load from json it doesn't work.

here's the data json on load_statistik_bidang.php:

```
[{"data":[["1",12],["1",11],["3",10],["14",9]],"label":"EMSA"},{"data":[["1",12],["4",9]],"label":"BSSA"},{"data":[["1",2],["1",10]],"label":"OSSAC"}]
```

if i copy the json in manual it's works but when im using function to load the data it doesnt work .

code that i load the json is like this :

```
function loadMyData(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"load_statistik_bidang.php",
            dataType: "json",
            method:"get",
            success: function(data){
                tampung = data;
                console.log(data.EMSA);
            }

        });
        }
var plot = $.plot($("#site_statistics"), tampung);
```

any ideas for this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is broken/invalid. You're not closing your first `data` array.

Should look like this:

```
[{
    "label": "EMSA",
    "data": [
        [
            "1",
            12
        ],
        [
            "1",
            11
        ]
        ] // <-- you forgot this
    },
    {
        "label": "BSSA",
        "data": [
            [
                "1",
                12
            ],
            [
                "4",
                9
            ]
        ]

    }
]
```

You can use this site to validate it in the future:
http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: no, my data array work properly, when i replace my json to variabel call "tampung" , it's work properly

Comment: Sorry my mistake doesnt copy properly my JSON code, i have edit my quesiton now. the JSON i've been test it is work properly but the problem is, it cannot load my json from my function loadMyData()